# Yii2 nex/datepicker widget onchange

Tags: yii, datepicker

I am trying to use a date picker field on a Yii2 application and set the onchange js function. I am using [this](https://github.com/RomeroMsk/yii2-datepicker) date picker. Can anybody show me how to set the onchange js function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `clientEvents` option to specify the bootstrap datetime picker's event [**`dp.change`**](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/)

> **`dp.change`** Fired when the date is changed.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `e = {
>       date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
>       oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null }`
>
> Emitted from:
>
> - `toggle()` Note: Only fired when using useCurrent
> - `show()` Note: Only
>     fired when using useCurrent or when or the date is changed to comply
>     with date rules (min/max etc)
> - `date(newDate)`
> - `minDate(minDate)`
> - `maxDate(maxDate)`
> - `daysOfWeekDisabled()`

To use it inside your active form you can use the following

```
echo $form->field ( $model , 'date_booking')->widget (
        nex\datepicker\DatePicker::className () , [
    'addon' => false ,
    'size' => 'sm' ,
    'clientEvents' => [
        'dp.change' => new \yii\web\JsExpression ( "function (e) { console.log(e.date,e.oldDate); }" ) ,
    ] ,
] );
```

Comment: you are welcome @ManosKardaris , do select the answer as correct, if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

May be This could help you.

```
$("#id").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#id').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
 });
```